# Expected number of comparisons for a basic sort algorithm

Tags: self-study, expected-value

Define a basic sort algorithm for 5 distinct numbers as 1 that selects a random element $x$ among the 5 numbers and compares it to the other numbers. The algorithm then divides the remaining elements into 2 groups $A$ and $B$, where the elements of $A$ are less than $x$ and the elements of $B$ are greater than $x$. The process is then repeated for elements in $A$ and $B$ until all 5 numbers are sorted in ascending order. What is the expected number of comparisons made? I tried brute forcing this but there is probably a better way of solving it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this. I used a tree diagram to describe the number of comparisons in each stage and then worked backwards. I also found a recursive formula that I used to match my answer. This formula is:

$T(n)=n-1+\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}T_i$ Where $T(n)$ is the expected number of comparisons for n numbers and $T(1)=0$.

$T(2)=1$.

$T(3)=8/3$.

$T(4)=29/6$.

$T(5)=111/15$.